# loop through Object in Javascript get from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello I have a PHP script that returns the following JSON :

```
[
    {
        "zone_name": "1st_zone"
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [
            "51.56256,-0.37903",
            "51.50789,-0.19913",
            "51.58475,-0.06729",
            "51.61461,-0.19638",
            "51.5711,-0.28152"
        ]
    },
    {
        "zone_name": "2nd_zone"
    },
    {
        "coordinates": [
            "51.56256,-0.37903",
            "51.50789,-0.19913",
            "51.58475,-0.06729",
            "51.61461,-0.19638",
            "51.5711,-0.28152",
            "51.57707,0.11398",
            "51.48651,0.12497",
            "51.56939,0.28427"
        ]
    }
]
```

In Javascript I'm doing an AJAX call like that :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "load_zone.php",   
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response){
            for(var i =0; i<response.length; i++){
                console.log(response[i]);
            }
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });
```

I get this result in console :

```
Object { zone_name="1st_zone"}
Object { coordinates=[5]}
Object { zone_name="2nd_zone"}
Object { coordinates=[8]}
```

How can I print each zone_name and coordinates separately?

Thanks

Comment: please describe the output you want - the result from your console does print the zone and coordinates separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i =0; i<response.length; i++){
   if(i%2 === 0) console.log(response[i].zone_name);
   else console.log(response[i].coordinates); 
  // console.log(response[i].zone_name || response[i].coordinates); //one liner
}
```

This will give you the respective zone names and coordinates. 
Your current JSON has an array of objects which list the zone names and coordinates as successive elements of the array.

But you should try to change your json to look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "zone_name": "1st_zone"
        "coordinates": [
            "51.56256,-0.37903",
            "51.50789,-0.19913",
            "51.58475,-0.06729",
            "51.61461,-0.19638",
            "51.5711,-0.28152"
        ]
    }
...
]
```

Which will mean that the array would contain objects representing a zone with its coordinates. Which can then be accessed like `response[i].zone_name` and `response[i].coordinates`.

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
$.each(data,function(index,item){

    console.log(item);
    $.each(item,function(index1,item1){
    console.log(item1);
    });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s98YR/)